# replace application with newer version 1.1 on android market

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded my application to android market https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zealous.estimatetracker&feature=search_result,bt there were some issues so i solved them and now i have new .apk file for API 2-16+.But i m not able to find any way to delete that previous app.and it is possible to give another version and publishing it.but i want to replace that application with new one..if any way to do that plzz suggest me..
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Log in to your android market developer console, click on the app you want to update. Then click on the "APK files" tab. From there, press the "Upload APK" button. After uploading you'll then have to deactivate your old version and then activate the new version.

Comment: is this the only way??becoz all deactivated apk files will reside there..so if something else is possible suggest me.

Comment: Nope, that is the only way to do it. The Android Market keeps every version that you ever upload. There is no way to remove the old ones.

Comment: Yeah and it's a good thing that the old APK files stay there. If your recent update happens to have a critical flaw, you can quickly roll back to an older version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload a new apk file with a higher build number. Then you use it to replace the old one.

Comment: thanks for the reply,,ya i have changed the version code and version number but there is only one option that i have to deactivate the old one and activate the new uploaded apk..It is just uploading new one not replacing the old one..pls suggest me any way to do that..

Comment: The old version will automatically become inactive when you activate the new one. There us only one active version of any app.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer stopped short of explaining the next step of de-activating the old version.

In the apk tab, in the upper right corner, click the "**Switch to Advance Mode**" link.

Click **De-activate** then select the new version you want to **activate**.

Click **Activate** and then click **save**.  Now, your new version is live on Google Play.